# Ejecutar sentencias GRANT a una base de datos remota en Postgres

Tags: base-de-datos, postgresql

quisiera automatizar la acción del grant para un usuario determinado *(myuser)* a todas las bases de datos dentro de una instancia Postgres **(desde la base/usuario Postgres)**. Mi primer intento fue hacer el siguiente script:

```
select dblink_exec('dbname=mibase host=IP user=usersuport password=xxx',
        'GRANT SELECT on all tables in schema public to myuser;');
```

Pero me arroja un mensaje haciendo referencia a que no puedo ejecutar ese tipo de sentencias, he probado haciendo uso del `EXEC` con los mismos resultados, he visto ejemplos pero solo he encontrado para casos de `update`, `delete` e `insert`, tampoco hay para `create`.

Cualquier idea sería de mucha ayuda.

Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

En realidad el acercamiento correcto para Postgres igual o mayor a la 9.3 sería usar la extensión FDW. Si no la tienes instalada, se instala con

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgres_fdw;
```

Luego creas una referencia a tu servidor remoto usando esa extensión:

```
  CREATE SERVER servidor_remoto
  FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw
  OPTIONS (host 'IP', dbname 'mibase');
```

Luego creas un mapeo de usuarios tal que uno de tus usuarios locales equivalga a un usuario remoto. Si el usuario remoto `usersuport` ya tiene permisos sobre `public` entonces puedes mapear al usuario local  `myuser` con el usuario remoto:

```
  CREATE USER MAPPING FOR myuser
  SERVER servidor_remoto
  OPTIONS (user 'usersuport', password 'xxx');
```

Luego "montas" un esquema remoto en un esquema local (no recuerdo si tienes que crear el esquema local o se crea explícitamente). Lo importante es que con este acercamiento todas las tablas del esquema remoto se mapean a FOREIGN TABLES en el esquema local:

```
IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA public
FROM SERVER servidor_remoto
INTO esquema_public_remoto;
```

Y finalmente, puedes darle permisos a tu usuario local sobre las tablas de tu esquema local:

```
GRANT SELECT on all tables in schema esquema_public_remoto to myuser;
```

Eso por debajo haría que tu usuario local pudiera ejecutar el select sin que tu BBDD local le diga: "Momento, tú no tienes permiso sobre este esquema", pero además, ya que antes lo mapeaste a un usuario remoto, una vez que el esquema lo deja hacer el select, además el servidor remoto no le va a decir: "momento, acá no hay nadie que se llame myuser".